# Facing issue while running a Python Script on Cisco CLI

Tags: python, cisco-ios

I am trying to write a Python Script to enable port-security on one of the interfaces of a Cisco Switch and bind them to a group of MAC_addresses, wherein I am taking the following as input from the users:

1. The number of MAC Addresses to be added
2. The MAC Addresses to be added.

My code is below:

```
tn = telnetlib.Telnet('192.168.1.10')
tn.read_until(b"Password:")
telpassword="P@ssw0rd"
tn.write(telpassword.encode('ascii')+ b'\r\n')
tn.write(b"enable"+b"\r\n")
tn.write(telpassword.encode('ascii')+ b'\r\n')
tn.write(b"config terminal"+ b"\r\n")
tn.write(b"interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/10"+ b"\r\n")
tn.write(b"switchport mode access"+ b"\r\n")
tn.write(b"switchport port-security"+ b"\r\n")
maxmac = input("How many MAC Addresses you want to add"+"\n")
tn.write(b"switchport port-security maximum"+ maxmac.encode('ascii') + b"\r\n")
macadd = input("Enter the MAC Address in the format xxxx.xxxx.xxxx"+"\n")
tn.write(b"switchport port-security mac-address"+ macadd.encode('ascii') + b"vlan access" + b"\r\n")
tn.write(b"switchport port-security violation shutdown" + b"\r\n")
tn.write(b"end" + b"\r\n")
tn.write(b"wr" + b"\r\n")
print("MAC_Address "+str(macadd)+" has been added")
```

When I am passing commands wherein I have to concatenate bytes and strings(after converted to bytes, my Cisco CLI is not recognozing those commands.Like for e.g. my Cisco CLI is not taking following 2 commands when passing through the script:

```
tn.write(b"switchport port-security maximum"+ maxmac.encode('ascii') + b"\r\n")
tn.write(b"switchport port-security mac-address"+ strmacadd.encode('ascii') + b"vlan access" + b"\r\n")
```

However it is very well taking the authentication passwords when passing through 
the following commands:

```
tn.write(telpassword.encode('ascii')+ b'\r\n')
```

I am facing some issue when my string commands(converted into bytes) are concatenated with an string user input(also converted into bytes) as shown above.

Please guide me,that in such a scenario what should be the correct way to pass the commands through the Cisco CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to take a look at this library: https://github.com/nickpegg/ciscolib